# Debugging in Netbeans with EclipseLink static weaving

Tags: netbeans, maven, eclipselink

I am attempting to debug unit tests in Netbeans 7 on classes that make use of the EclipseLink static weaving.  If I turn off static weaving I can get debug a unit test, but I cannot get a non-debug run of the tests to build (as expected).  If I turn static weaving on I cannot debug the tests.

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <java classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave"
                              classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" fork="true">
                            <arg line="-loglevel FINE -persistenceinfo src/main/resources target/classes target/classes"/>
                        </java>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I am guessing I need to have the static weaving get picked up when debugging? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A hack fix seems to be to turn dynamic weaving on for the unit tests while leaving it as static for the release version... ick.